# Cmake seems not to use the Python interpreter it confirms it uses

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, rpm, cpack

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file, which is instructed to use Python 3.4

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../cmake/")

project(aConfigd VERSION 1.0)
string(TOLOWER aConfigd project_id)

find_package(PythonInterp 3.4 REQUIRED)

include(FindPythonInterp)
set(PYTHON ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE})
message(STATUS "\${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} == ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
set(pkgdatadir /usr/share/configd)
set(configdir /etc/amy)
set(SONARCONFIGID_SOURCE_DIR etc/configd)
set(SRC_DIR configd/src/)

include(common)
#        "${SRC_DIR}/systemd_client.py"
#        "${SRC_DIR}/amyconfig_service.py"
        "${SRC_DIR}/__init__.py"
        "${SRC_DIR}/main.py"
        "${SRC_DIR}/application.py"
        DESTINATION ${pkgdatadir}/configd/
)

#general
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "a-config")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "a-config-manager")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "a-config-manager")

# redhat
set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION 
      /etc/amy
      )

include(cpack)
```

Indeed, it confirms that `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} == /usr/bin/python3.4` (see 4th line below):

```
$ make clean ; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSHORT_VERSION=NO -DCUSTOMER=NO .. ;  make -j12 ; make package
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.5", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found version "3.4.5") 
-- ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} == /usr/bin/python3.4
-- Build Type: Release
-- Detected distribution: rhel fedora
-- Detected aConfigd version: 2.3.0-3030-gf7733cf659
-- Detected distribution: rhel fedora
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /local/raid0/git/amy/aConfig/build
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using RPM
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: aConfigd
CPack: - Install project: aConfigd
CPack: Create package
CPackRPM:Warning: CPACK_SET_DESTDIR is set (=ON) while requesting a relocatable package (CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE is set): this is not supported, the package won't be relocatable.
CPackRPM: Will use GENERATED spec file: /local/raid0/git/my/aConfig/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/SPECS/a-config.spec
CPack: - package: /local/raid0/git/my/aConfig/build/a-config-2.3.0-3030-gf7733cf659.el7.my.x86_64.rpm generated.
$
```

However, if I uncomment the `"${SRC_DIR}/systemd_client.py"` line, I get the error:

```
Compiling /local/raid0/git/my/aConfig/build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/a-config-2.3.0-3030-gf7733cf659.el7.my.x86_64/usr/share/configd/configd/systemd_client.py ...
  File "/usr/share/configd/configd/systemd_client.py", line 21
    def __init__(self, systemd_proxy:Gio.DBusProxy):
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Isn't `def __init__(self, systemd_proxy:Gio.DBusProxy): a valid Python 3.4` syntax?

If yes, why does Cmake complains?**

Answer (score 3):

The root-cause occurs in the rpmbuild step.
RPM is trying to be extra-helpful, and tries to (byte-code) compile .py files it encounters.
Alas, it wrongly uses the python2 interpreter to create a file's byte-code (even though `find_package(PythonInterp 3.4 REQUIRED)` is declared in the CMakeLists.txt file).

The fix that worked for me was:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_BUILDREQUIRES python34-devel)
set(CPACK_RPM_SPEC_MORE_DEFINE "%define __python ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just run `"${SRC_DIR}/systemd_client.py"`, you're telling it to run that script the same way it would be run by the shell: by looking at the `#!` line and running it with whatever interpreter is specified there. Which is probably something like `#! /usr/bin/python` or `#! /usr/bin/env python`.

If you want to run your script with a particular interpreter, you have to run that interpreter and pass it the script—just as you would at the shell. I'm pretty rusty with CMake, but I'd assume you do that like this:

```
"${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" "${SRC_DIR}/amyconfig_service.py"
```

Alternatively, since this is your code, maybe you want to use `setuptools` to programmatically generate scripts for your entry-points, which means it would create a `#!` line for them that runs whichever Python version was used to run `setup.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @abarnert. However, seems the root-cause lies elsewhere: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622146/1656850.

Comment: Regarding `setuptools`: setuptools is great at building compartmentalized Python modules that go into PYTHON_PATH, not so great at installing system-wide configuration to go with a standalone application. (And it doesn't do much to help with build-time configuration). Whereas most Python programs are simple in terms of outside dependencies, this one adds several bits and pieces, so, we should be using a build tool that ensures those all go in the right place depending on what platform we're building from.

Comment: @boardrider `setuptools` is how you install ipython, modernize, scrapy, pylint, black, and all kinds of other scripts—including pip itself. Even if your ultimate goal is to build a standalone program (with, e.g., a Windows installer package, macOS .dmg, etc.), most of the tools for doing that build on `setuptools`.

Comment: @boardrider With `setuptools`, I just give it my entry-point(s) and it automatically creates my script(s)—with the appropriate shbang line for the user's setup, and in a way that works on Windows as well as *nix—and figures out where to put them so it ends up on the user's `PATH` and so on, so all they have to do is `pip install spam` (or, better, `python3 -m pip install spam)` and now they can run `spamify`.'

Comment: The application in question needs to create configuration files outside of the Python directory tree (e.g., /usr/share, /usr/lib/systemd/system, /etc/dbus-1/system.d/, /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services, /etc, /usr/bin, et al.)