# cmake: brp-python-bytecompile and python3

Tags: python-3.x, rpm, cpack

I am trying to create a `python3` package using `cpack` (cmake). For some reason it is failing with a cryptic message:

```
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-comment-note /usr/bin/strip /usr/bin/objdump
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.rt2mTp (%install)
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.rt2mTp (%install)
 ***
CPackRPM:Debug:    - /mnt/source/bin2/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/rpmbuildsource-python.out
CPackRPM:Debug: *** Building target platforms: x86_64
Building for target x86_64
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mxEjdh
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.rt2mTp
Compiling /mnt/source/bin/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/project-0.0.8-Linux/python/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/project/__init__.py ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/project/__init__.py", line 27
    raise ValueError(f"Not a {obj.__class__.__name__} reference")
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to skip `brp-python-bytecompile` step, or else is there a way to instruct `cpack` that the python package only target `python3`.

For reference:

```
# head -1 source/python/__init__.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Rely on the `/bin` hack
2. Change the default value for `__python`

For solution #1, you simply need to use a `bin` subfolder. Any python bytecompilation which happen in a sub-directory of `/bin` will not be done:

- [`compileall.compile_dir` behavior related to parent directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065438/compileall-compile-dir-behavior-related-to-parent-directory-name)

For solution #2, you simply need to follow:

- [Changes/No more automagic Python bytecompilation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/No_more_automagic_Python_bytecompilation#Status_quo)

For cmake the syntax is:

```
set(CPACK_RPM_SPEC_MORE_DEFINE "%define __python python3")
```

See also an alternate solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622146/136285

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation some minutes ago.
In my case, my dev environment uses python 3 at a specific path, while the linux env has the 2.7 python bin (which is /usr/bin/python).

So, what I did was next:

```
...
/usr/bin/rpmbuild -bb --define "_python_override ${PYTHON_OVERRIDE}" ...
...
```

That is on a sh file which first calculates the path of python 3 and stores it at

**$PYTHON_OVERRIDE**

Then, on the spec file

```
%define __python %{_python_override}/python
```

With this, I make sure the RPM uses the same version I use to compile my python project.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have the same issue and I was able to skip brp-python-bytecompile step with the following: set(CPACK_RPM_SPEC_MORE_DEFINE "%undefine __python")